# How can I export my passwords to other machines?

Tags: password, password-store

I just installed [pass](http://www.passwordstore.org/) on my primary machine and I really like using it. I work on three or four machines and I'd like to synchronize all the passwords I have under `~/.password-store` to all my machines. Is this possible? If so, what would be the safest way to do so?

Comment: I keep my pass store in a directory managed by [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/): it works perfectly...

Comment: I have a directory on my machine managed by owncloud. Would moving `~/.password-store` to `~/ownCloud/.password-store` accomplish this? If I performed this migration, then would I have to tell `pass` where I moved the directory?

Comment: There is an environment variable for the password store location: see the bottom on `man pass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way that comes to one's mind (especially of someone who doesn't know what `pass` is): use SSH - i.e. `scp` (`sftp` or `ssh` would  work as well).

Yet looking at the [pass webpage](http://www.passwordstore.org/):

> It is a very short and simple shell script. It's capable of temporarily putting passwords on your clipboard and tracking password changes using `git`.

offers a more elegant method. Just use a Git repository as storage backend and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

If you always edit your passwords on the same machine, use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync):

```
rsync -a ~/.password-store foo.example.com:
```

to repliacate them from the current machine to `foo.example.com`, or

```
rsync -a master.example.com:.password-store ~
```

to replicate them from `master.example.com` to the current machine.

If you edit your passwords on different machines, you can use [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), which is like rsync, but bidirectional. Pick one machine as the master, say `master.example.com`. On each other machine, create a profile file `~/.unison/passwords.pdf`

```
root = /home/brian/.password-store
root = ssh://master.example.com/.password-store
```

Run `unison -auto passwords` from `foo.example.com` to propagate changes made since the last synchronization. Unison will automatically determine which side has the newer content on a per-file basis, and will ask you to pick if a file has been changed on both sides.